# Add line breaks to Grep Commands

Tags: linux, bash, text-processing, cygwin, word-processing

How can I add a few line breaks? I want it to show `OpenFin` category, have a line break, `Chrome` category, another line break, then `memoryInfo`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
cat LoginExInternal.txt | grep OpenFin >> LoginExcInternal.txt | echo $'\r' 
&& cat LoginExInternal.txt | grep Chrome >> LoginExcInternal.txt | echo $'\r' 
&& cat MemoryUnderThreshold.txt | grep memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit:1 >> LoginExcInternal.txt | echo $'\r'
```

I can't seem to get it into new lines though, the `echo $'\r'` doesn't seem to work. Please tell me how I can modify to make this work.

Comment: It would help to see (a reasonable part of) the contents of your files `LoginExInternal.txt` and `MemoryUnderThreshold.txt` and how the result should look like. Do you use `\r` (`CR`) to get DOS/Windows line endings (`\r`+`\n` or `CR`+`LF`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `cat` with `grep`, and you can group the commands to only put the redirection there once:

```
{
  grep OpenFin < LoginExInternal.txt && echo 
  grep Chrome < LoginExInternal.txt && echo
  grep memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit:1 < MemoryUnderThreshold.txt && echo
} >> LoginExcInternal.txt
```

Note also that if you join all the commands with `&&`, then a failing grep will stop the following `echo`, but also the rest of the `grep`s from running. That may or may not be what you want. Using just `grep && echo` as above would have all the `grep`s run in any case, but only print the extra newlines when the `grep` matches something.

Also, I'm not exactly sure how linebreaks are handled in cygwin, that is, if explicitly printing out the carriage return `$'\r'` is required.

Comment: This did not work for me. This is a part of a bigger script, when I added it, it said the grep command was not found. I think I will use what I have as it works, thanks for trying to help!

Comment: @IbrahimA, grouping with braces shouldn't affect what commands are found or not, so if you had grep working in the original, I can't see why it wouldn't work here.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work. I am not sure if there is a simpler way to do this:

```
grep OpenFin LoginExInternal.txt >> LoginExcInternal.txt && 
echo $'\r' >> LoginExcInternal.txt && 
grep Chrome LoginExInternal.txt >> LoginExcInternal.txt &&
echo $'\r' >> LoginExcInternal.txt &&
grep MemoryUnderThreshold.txt memoryInfo:jsHeapSizeLimit:1 >> LoginExcInternal.txt
```

Comment: You don't need the `cat` commands. Instead of `cat filename | grep pattern` simply use `grep pattern filename`.

Comment: Great Point! I just changed it and it works perfectly.